# What's the name of the manga about a guy who gets isekaied, arrives in a monster forest before meeting a female knight who doesn't understand him?

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I've been trying to find this manga. The mc gets isekaied to a demon forest and somehow makes it out. He then meets a female knight that he can't understand, because they don't speak the same language, so she takes him to a nun/priestess who casts a spell that lets him understand them. I think I remember him claiming to have amnesia to cover his back story. The nun/priests takes care of him until they think he's ready and capable on surviving on his own. Then eventually the nun/priestess gets charmed/hypnotized and taken by a demon/vampire/Incubus impersonating a noble/mayor/aristocrat. So the mc goes to save her and ends up fighting and defeated him with the female knight from the beginning of the story's help. The female knight is injuried or poisoned to where she goes into extreme heat(horny). The mc has sex with her to save her. I think I remember there being a special or powerful sword not sure if it was involved in saving the female knight. The nun I believe is unable to be saved and dies. The mc and the female knight team up for now and continue on a journey.

Not too sure but I think that the mc was special in a certain way when he was taught magic by the nun in the beginning. He might have been able to use all types of magic or something and kept it a secret considering it was abnormal for people in that world.

That's about as much as I remember from the manga.

Comment: The first few sentences sound a lot like [this story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265735). But the sex bit never happens, and the MC is not powerful. It's definitely not the story you're looking for, but is it possible you're mixing up details from multiple stories?

Comment: [Another possibility](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275193), again with a lot of differences. Nun saves him from the forest, no language barrier, female knight doesn't go into heat, but there is a very suggestive scene with her. It match: Nun dies; due to a demon impersonator (as a priest); special sword is involved (pulled from her breasts); he does go on a journey with the female knight; I'm pretty sure he unusually has all attributes; definitely taught magic by nun at the start

Comment: The combination of these two seems like a good match. I wasn't able to find any better matches with some quick searches. I can continue looking if you confirm that you aren't mixing up any details from either of these two.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been trying to bring this one to mind for weeks, based on the forest, female knight and not understanding the language and finally found it: [Isekai Demo Bunan ni Ikitai Shoukougun](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekai-demo-bunan-ni-ikitai-shoukougun). The first two chapters are free on [Magcomi](https://magcomi.com/episode/10834108156766386086) and while I don’t know about the later stuff, at a brief look it has the forest, female knight and nun/priestess:

[image: isekai’d into a forest]
[image: female knight speaking different language]
[image: nun/priestess]